# Both n and percent labels on geom_col, ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

If I plot `df` with the code below, I can put the n for each column over the column itself, [as seen in this example plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyTUZ.png). What I would like to do is also put the percentage for each column in the label. That is the percentage of the total that the column makes up. So, for example, the label on the first column would read `127(42.9%)`, instead of just `127`. How could I do that?

```
df <- structure(list(Letter = structure(1:7,
      .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"),
      class = "factor"), Freq = c(127L, 101L, 24L, 19L, 3L, 0L, 22L)),
      .Names = c("Letter", "Freq"),
      row.names = c(NA, -7L),
      class = "data.frame")

ggplot(df, aes(Letter, Freq, label = Freq)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(size = 3, position = position_dodge(width = 1), vjust = -0.25)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create the text you want to use as a label.

```
df$pct = df$Freq / sum(df$Freq) * 100
df$label = sprintf("%s (%s%%)", df$Freq, round(df$pct, 1))

ggplot(df, aes(Letter, Freq, label = label)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(size = 3, position = position_dodge(width = 1), vjust = -0.25)
```

[image]